# C++ pointers and references data type

Tags: c++, pointers, types, reference

In his book "The C++ Programming Language" (4th edition), the author (Bjarne Stroustrup) says in page 138:

> From these types, we can construct other types using declarator operators:
>   §7.2 Pointer types (such as `int∗`)
>   §7.3 Array types (such as `char[]`)
>   §7.7 Reference types (such as `double&` and `vector<int>&&`)

Which confuses me a bit.

I have a basic understanding of pointer, array and reference operators and I know that they are related to memory addresses.

But if I have a code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float Var;

    float& Var_Ref = Var;

    float* Var_ptr;
    Var_ptr = &Var;

    cout << "\n\n Type of Var is " << typeid(Var).name();
    cout << "\n\n Type of Var_ptr is " << typeid(Var).name();
    cout << "\n\n Type of Var_Ref is " << typeid(Var).name();

    getch();

    cout << "\n\n\n";
}
```

And the output is:

[image: Output]

I can see that `typeid.name()` returns the type they are related to not the type of the variables themselves.

I suppose that:

`Var_Ref` is of type `float&` (an alias for the `float` variable `Var`)
`Var_ptr` is of type `float*` (pointer to the variable `Var` that has a `float` type)

Especially for the pointer which when printed show an integral hex value of a memory location.

**Q**: Are these real data types? Am I missing something?

Comment: you have typeid(Var).name() 3 times in your code.

Comment: I count it as simple typographical mistake.

Comment: @George in that link at the bottom there's an example of it's usage with a pointer to a double and it outputs `double*`

Comment: @picklechips Ah derp, thanks for pointing that out :-) it's a false assumption for reference types.* see [ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)

Comment: Thanks @TonyJ. Over focusing. I spent 3 hours on it without noticing that I did not edited the pasted line. Now the output makes sense. Thanks a lot. :). and thanks for all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, these are still real datatypes.

Pointers point to an address space in the memory. For example,

```
int test = 5;
int *foo = &test;
```

& will get the address that test is located at. *foo just states that foo will be storing the address.

With this in mind, foo will not = 5. But rather some hex address such as 0xA000125BFFFFFF or something weird like that.

If this helps, some people like to write:

```
int* foo
```

So you can think of this as a int pointer called foo.

But, one thing to point out is that all of these are type int. This will apply to another datatype such as float or double or some other custom one.

However, one thing to note is that you cannot do this:

```
double test = 5.02;
int *foo = &test;
```

Comment: `int* foo` is bad, as that makes people think that `int* foo, bar` makes two int pointers, where in actuality `foo` is a pointer, and `bar` is a int.

Comment: I agree, I don't necessarily recommend doing it that way. I am use to 'int *foo'. But in some code from other people, I have seen them write 'int* foo'. I just mentioned it here in the hopes that the OP will have a better understanding of the topic

Comment: Is fair, just wanted that on the table.  I've worked places where the style requires `int* bar`, and it just drives me nuts because of this.

Comment: Darn, still learning the comments section. Above is suppose to be `int *foo` and `int* foo` respectively

Comment: I would argue that `int* foo` is not what leads to confusion. The fact is `int* foo, bar;` meaning `int *foo; int bar;` is inconsistent with other parts of the language. Just about anywhere else, the `*` is part of the type.

Comment: Where is `*` part of the type outside of conversation (where we talk about "int pointers")?